# Show users their domain using their IP

Tags: php, html, networking

I'm sorry in advance for my poor wording. I was given this snippet of code at class to identify if the visitor to our page was from our schools domain -- we hosted it on the schools server.

I will be moving this to a different site for hosting, so the current code won't be accurate.

Is there a way to make this snippet of code relevant and show the visitor the strings I'm echoing relevant to their IP?

```
    $IPv4 = explode(".", $ip);
    if($IPv4[0] == "10" || ($IPv4[0] == "131" && $IPv4[1] == "125"))
    {
        echo "<br>You are from XXX domain.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>You are not from XXX domain.";
    }
```

Comment: You need to find out your school's public IP range, and replace `10.131.125` with that range.

Comment: @barmar Thank you so much! Ill try that out!

Comment: The codes check 10.X.X.X and 131.125.X.X and regard those in this range as from XXX domain (so you need to replace with your new IP address information. For example if your new site's public IP is 201.12.3.7, please replace 131 with 201 and replace 125 with 12)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out your schools IP. Lets say it was 10.20.30.40.
Then you can just check via:

```
  if($IPv4[0] == "10" && ($IPv4[1] == "20" && $IPv4[2] == "30"))
```

The last part doesn't really matter because it can change. Notice that you really have to check if **all** the parts match, not only one or two. If they do, you can be sure that the request comes from the school.